# Dapper - using multimapping with split points other than Id

Tags: dapper

I know this is similar to [Correct use of Multimapping in Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/correct-use-of-multimapping-in-dapper), but I think it's slightly different.

I have the following POCO structure:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int customerkey { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
    public int statekey { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }

    public Customer()
    {
        this.Invoices = new List<Invoice>();
    }
}

public class Invoice
{
    public int customerinvoicekey { get; set; }
    public int customerkey { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int statuskey { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
}

public class State
{   
    public int statekey { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to map this using Dapper and I'm not using Id for my split points.  I can get it to work if I double up the keys, but I'm not sure why I have to do that.

Why does this work:

```
const string commandText =
        @"SELECT 
        A.customerkey, A.FirstName, A.LastName, A.EmailAddress, A.statuskey,
        C.statuskey, C.Description,
        B.customerinvoicekey, B.customerkey, B.Number, B.Description, B.Total, B.statuskey,
        D.statuskey, D.Description
        FROM Web.TestCustomers2 A
        INNER JOIN Web.TestCustomerInvoices2 B ON A.customerkey = B.customerkey
        INNER JOIN Web.TestStatus2 C ON A.statuskey = C.statuskey
        INNER JOIN Web.TestStatus2 D ON B.statuskey = D.statuskey
        ORDER BY A.customerkey";

        var customers = new List<Customer>();
        Customer currentCustomer = null;
        db.Connection.Query<Customer, State, Invoice, State, Customer>(commandText,
            (customer, customerstate, invoice, invoicestate) =>
            {
                if (currentCustomer == null || currentCustomer.customerkey != customer.customerkey)
                {
                    customers.Add(customer);
                    currentCustomer = customer;
                }
                invoice.State = invoicestate;
                currentCustomer.Invoices.Add(invoice);
                currentCustomer.State = customerstate;
                return currentCustomer;
            }, splitOn: "statuskey,customerinvoicekey,statuskey");
```

But this does not work (leaving out the select of statuskey in A and B):

```
const string commandText =
        @"SELECT 
        A.customerkey, A.FirstName, A.LastName, A.EmailAddress,
        C.statuskey, C.Description,
        B.customerinvoicekey, B.customerkey, B.Number, B.Description, B.Total,
        D.statuskey, D.Description
        FROM Web.TestCustomers2 A
        INNER JOIN Web.TestCustomerInvoices2 B ON A.customerkey = B.customerkey
        INNER JOIN Web.TestStatus2 C ON A.statuskey = C.statuskey
        INNER JOIN Web.TestStatus2 D ON B.statuskey = D.statuskey
        ORDER BY A.customerkey";

        var customers = new List<Customer>();
        Customer currentCustomer = null;
        db.Connection.Query<Customer, State, Invoice, State, Customer>(commandText,
            (customer, customerstate, invoice, invoicestate) =>
            {
                if (currentCustomer == null || currentCustomer.customerkey != customer.customerkey)
                {
                    customers.Add(customer);
                    currentCustomer = customer;
                }
                invoice.State = invoicestate;
                currentCustomer.Invoices.Add(invoice);
                currentCustomer.State = customerstate;
                return currentCustomer;
            }, splitOn: "statuskey,customerinvoicekey,statuskey");
```

Comment: are you using the latest dapper from google code?

Comment: I'm using the latest nuget package - version 1.6.

Comment: Just to be sure, I tried the latest dapper from google code with the same result.  An exception is thrown - "When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id
Parameter name: splitOn"

Comment: I had a similar exception when using the spliton with a custom unique id for one specific table. I have now changed my method to create a custom poco class and let the query get only what I want rather than bring everything.

Answer (score 1):

Where exactly `customerinvoicekey` coming from?

Your model claims the key for the table is `public int customerkey { get; set; }`.

If you split on a column that is not in your models the behaviour of the multi-mapping functions is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, for that test, I missed customerinvoicekey in my Invoice class and updated my question above to reflect the change. The same exception is thrown.