# Dapper Multi Mapping with QueryMultiple

Tags: .net, sql, dapper

I have a stored procedure that returns multiple result sets. I'm executing this with dapper.

One of the result sets is Person JOIN Checks, where Person can have many Checks.

The end goal is to have distinct person objects that have a collection of check objects.

`QueryMultiple` gives me a `Sqlmapper.GridReader`. I see an overload of `SqlMapper.GridReader.Read()` that takes a `Func<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn>`.

Is there an example of how to use this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I got it working:

```cs
var q = _sqlConnection.QueryMultiple("MySproc",
                                     myParams,
                                     commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
var set1 = q.Read<Set1Type>();

var set2Func = new Func<Person, Check, Person>((p, c) => {
    p.CheckAlert = c;
    return p;
});

var set2 = q.Read(set2Func, "CheckId")
            .GroupBy(x => x.PersonId)
            .Select(x => {
                var person = x.First();
                person.Checks = x.Select(p => p.Check).ToArray();
                person.Check = null; // i really don't like this
                return person;
            })
            .ToArray();
```

As the comment says, I don't like the unneeded check property on the Person object.

I'd still love to hear of a better way of doing this.

Comment: +1, but it may be worth *not* accepting this as the answer if you are looking for a better way to do it, since unanswered questions seem to attract more attention.

Comment: What's "CheckId", where are you getting that from?

Comment: Got it - it's the [splitOn:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7478958/575530) parameter

Comment: What's the difference between p.CheckAlert and person.Check?

Comment: All of that stuff is from my model.

Comment: No need to roll you own solution when Dapper is capable to handle this situation quite easily https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/452#issuecomment-182505793

Answer (score 9):

Here's a version of the solution I used. I side-stepped the issue Ronnie raised in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12978912/575530) using an inheritance hierachy instead of setting a property to null, but it amounts to much the same thing.

Here's the SQL: users have items and collections, and items can be in collections.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Users
(id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (NEWID()) NOT NULL,
name NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
email NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id))

CREATE TABLE Items
(id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (NEWID()) NOT NULL,
userId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
name NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
description NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES Users (id))

CREATE TABLE Collections
(id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (NEWID()) NOT NULL,
userId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
name NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
layoutSettings NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES Users (id))

CREATE TABLE CollectedItems
(itemId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
collectionId  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (itemId, collectionId),
FOREIGN KEY (itemId) REFERENCES Items (id),
FOREIGN KEY (collectionId) REFERENCES Collections (id))
```

Now the data model classes. Collections are a little more complicated than I would expect in order to deal with Dapper multi mapping with multiple queries.

```csharp
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public List<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class CoreCollection
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LayoutSettings { get; set; }
}

public class PartialDataCollection : CoreCollection
{
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
}

public class Collection : CoreCollection
{
    public List<Guid> ItemIds { get; set; }
}

public class CollectedItem
{
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public Guid CollectionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Finally we have the controller method which uses Dapper multi mapping with multiple queries

```csharp
[Route("GetUser/{id}")]
public User GetUser(Guid id)
{
    var sql = @"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = @id
                SELECT * FROM Items WHERE userId = @id
                SELECT * FROM Collections 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN CollectedItems ON Collections.id = CollectedItems.collectionId  
                    WHERE userId = @id";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new { id = id });
        var user = multi.Read<User>().Single();
        var items = multi.Read<Item>().ToList();
        var partialDataCollections = multi.Read<PartialDataCollection, CollectedItem, PartialDataCollection>(AddCollectedItem, splitOn: "itemId").ToList();

        user.Items = items;

        user.Collections = partialDataCollections.GroupBy(
            pdc => pdc.Id,
            (key, group) => new Collection
            {
                Id = key,
                UserId = group.First().UserId,
                Name = group.First().Name,
                LayoutSettings = group.First().LayoutSettings,
                ItemIds = group.Select(groupMember => groupMember.ItemId).ToList()
            }).ToList();

        return user;
    }
}

private PartialDataCollection AddCollectedItem(PartialDataCollection collection, CollectedItem collectedItem)
{
    if (collection != null && collectedItem != null)
    {
        collection.ItemId = collectedItem.ItemId;
    }
    return collection;
}
```

Where Ronnie is anxious about setting `person.Check = null` in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12978912/575530) I am anxious about the additional complexity in my answer from adding the class `PartialDataCollection` to my model. But I cannot see a simple way around that.

(N.B. I have raised this as [an issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/452) on the Dapper GitHub project.)