# Returning a single parameter as part of multi mapping query

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a scenario where I need to return a single column as part of a multi map query in *Dapper*.

I've simplified the example below but in essence the single column value (the int) I want to retrieve is not a property on the Post class (but is in the database table).

I want to fetch this value on it's own as use it in a manner similar to the following line from the example, where status is the int value in question:

```
post.SetSomeStatus(status);
```

Here is the code example:

```
  var sql = 
    @"select *, p.Status from #Posts p 
    left join #Users u on u.Id = p.OwnerId
    Order by p.Id";

    var data = connection.Query<Post, User, int, Post>(sql, (post, user, status) => { 
        post.Owner = user;
        post.SetSomeStatus(status);
        return post;
    });

    var post = data.First();
```

I'm seeing the following error with this code: *Index was outside the bounds of the array*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error: *Index was outside of the bounds of the array* was due to the way Dapper was splitting up the segments of the query response to be allocated across the return parameters Post, User & int in this example. The convention of Dapper is to split on the field ID or provide your own rules to split up the result set using the *splitOn* parameter.

To make the above example work:

```
  var sql = 
    @"select *, p.Status AS ID from #Posts p 
    left join #Users u on u.Id = p.OwnerId
    Order by p.Id";

    var data = connection.Query<Post, User, int, Post>(sql, (post, user, status) => { 
        post.Owner = user;
        post.SetSomeStatus(status);
        return post;
    });

    var post = data.First();
```

I found another question that also helped me: [Correct use of Multimapping in Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/correct-use-of-multimapping-in-dapper)