# Value objects with Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper, aggregateroot, value-objects

I have an entity with an aggregated value object, like this:

```
public class Address {
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Contact {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

My persistence model is a single table with the following fields: `Id, Name, Street, Town, Region`, ecc. Is it possible to Create/Read/Update/Delete entities in this situation with Dapper?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct use of Multimapping in Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/correct-use-of-multimapping-in-dapper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the multi mapping feature.
Here there are some examples:

[Correct use of Multimapping in Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/correct-use-of-multimapping-in-dapper)