# model with list from sql

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2012, asp.net-web-api2

I have a model with list property like as below

```
 [DataContract]
public class question
{
    [DataMember]
    public int questionsid { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string questions { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string correctanswer { get; set; }        
    [DataMember]
    public int questionpaperid { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime createddate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string createdby { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime modifieddate { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string modifiedby { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<answer> options { get; set; }
}
```

How to fill model with all property from database(SQL QUERY)

Comment: Use Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Use ORM for this like Entity Framework or Dapper.

see this link for Dapper [Correct use of Multimapping in Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/correct-use-of-multimapping-in-dapper)

Comment: Dapper is not an ORM. Entity Framework just does this automatically. It uses foreign key relationships to infer a database structure (which you can further customize) and would accomplish this automatically. You can't equate these tools.

Comment: @AluanHaddad the question is about how to fill the model from sql and not about ORM debate for dapper