# C# Passing Dapper POCO and Dapper.Fluent EntityMap as a arguments

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I am currently trying to setup work with MySQL db via dapper.

I have declared POCO for dapper:

```
public class DevicesOnTesterDbTable 
{
    public string UUID { get; set; }
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }
    public string DeviceAddedAt { get; set; }
    public uint Address { get; set; }
}
```

I also have Dapper.Fluent EntityMap for that table:

```
public class DevicesOnTesterDbTableMap : EntityMap<DevicesOnTesterDbTable>
{
    public DevicesOnTesterDbTableMap()
    {
        Map(p => p.UUID).ToColumn("devices_on_tester_uuid");
        Map(p => p.DeviceType).ToColumn("devices_on_tester_type");
        Map(p => p.DeviceAddedAt).ToColumn("devices_on_tester_add_at");
        Map(p => p.Address).ToColumn("devices_on_tester_address");
    }
}
```

My database have about ten tables so i have ten pairs of POCO and EntityMap classes for them. So in case of reading i have to perform something like this for each table:

```
public static List<DevicesOnTesterDbTable> ReadDevices(string server)
{
    FluentMapper.Initialize(config =>
    {
        config.AddMap(new DevicesOnTesterDbTableMap());
    });

    try
    {
        using (var mySqlConnection = OpenConnection(server))
        {
            mySqlConnection.Open();
            return mySqlConnection.Query<DevicesOnTesterDbTable>("Select * from power_source_calibration").ToList();
         }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }           
}
```

Now is there a way to pass this pairs into some other method that will perform common operations such as read\write\update etc? Or maybe there is some better way around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a better way around; actually you are doing it wrong.

You do not need to call `FluentMapper.Initialize` in each of your method like `ReadDevices`. Ideally, all your mappings (for all entities) should happen only once at the startup of your application.

Following is from [here](http://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper-fluentmap):

> Initialize your mapping at the **start** of your application.
>
> ```
> FluentMapper.Initialize(config =>
> {
>     config.AddMap(new InvoiceMap());
> });
> ```

Also, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44789056/5779732) question which shows how to do it at application startup. Refer `Register()` method which is `static` and caller call it once at application startup somewhere.