# Dapper Query() returned multiple same column

Tags: c#, winforms, dapper

I'm using dapper Query method to fetch a set of data from sqlite with left join, it does return the column i need but multiple times.

i tried these query on DB Browser it works fine,

```
 string sql =
         @"select a.id, a.alert_tag, lyr.layer_name, ln.line_name, t.task_name from alert_tag a
              LEFT JOIN layer_group lyr on lyr.layerID = a.layer_group
              LEFT JOIN line ln on ln.lineID = a.line
              LEFT JOIN task t on t.taskID = a.task";
```

then i call it,

```
using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(Tools.LoadConnectionString()))
{
    var output = cnn.Query<dynamic>(sql);
    return output.ToList();
}
```

```
List<dynamic> Alerttag_List = new List<dynamic>();

private void LoadDGVdata()
{
     Alerttag_List = SqliteQuery_AlertTagModel.Load();
     dgv_AlertTag.DataSource = Alerttag_List;
}
```

I expected to get result like these

```
| id | alert_tag | layer_name | line_name | task_name |
```

but i got these

```
| id | alert_tag | layer_name | line_name | task_name | id | alert_tag | layer_name | line_name | task_name |
```

Comment: What happens when you run the query directly against the database

Comment: i got the 5 columns that i wanted, without duplicates.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the grid binding, to be honest. Can you do: `var propCount = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Alerttag_List[0]).Count` and tell me what it says? is it 5, or is it 10?

Comment: also: how many rows are there in this example? is it 2 perhaps? I wonder whether the grid is generating a column per unique `PropertyDescriptor` reference, but the `RowBoundPropertyDescriptor` that dapper is exposing here is transient (generated on the fly per row). Also: what kind of grid is that? i.e. is this `DataGridView` ? or...? And: does this perhaps *gain* columns, i.e. you have `AutoGenerateColumns` (or whatever) enabled, and it is adding them whenever you change the source?

Comment: Side note: generating a POCO class and mapping to *that* (i.e. `Query<YourType>`) should be very reliable - the dynamic property API via `PropertyDescriptor` however, is... twitchy

Comment: @MarcGravell it counted 10, i tried add another row it still shows 10 column, and i tried Query<MyType> but it shows rows with blank cells in my grid.

Comment: its `DataGridView`, now i try not to use dapper, but use `SQLiteCommand > SQLiteDataReader`, it works only shows me 5 column. but dont know what is the cause of using dapper and returned 10 cols.

Comment: @espifi059espifi059 I just want to be 100% clear: `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Alerttag_List[0]).Count` returned 10? because if so, yeah, that's very interesting and that gives me somewhere to start

Comment: it returned 10 when i use dapper's `Query<>`, and returned 5 when i use `SQLiteCommand`

Comment: You are probably looking for the "splitOn" command.  If that correct, please consider removing this question. (as it would be a duplicate)  see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/correct-use-of-multimapping-in-dapper

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `ExecuteReader`. it will return single data.
Example:

```
public dynamic GetTableData(string schemaName, string tableName)
        {
            string sql = $@"select * from {schemaName}.{tableName}";
            var tableData = _sqlConnection.ExecuteReader(sql);
            return tableData;
        }
```

[image: Debug Pic]

Comment: ExecuteReader is not compatible with `dynamic` AFAIK (context: I wrote it). And even if it was, I don't think that is the problem here.

Comment: ExecuteReader from dapper. I have already tested. and edited the answer with a picture.

Comment: Hello Marc, Maybe same thing but for bindable grid/treelist problem happens. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66096906/how-to-return-unique-columns-only-with-join-statement-in-dapper-query-sql