# How to use Dapper to automatically map remaining columns to dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mapping, dapper, dto

I am attempting to use Dapper to map to my DTO:

```
public class MyDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalColumns { get; set; }
}
```

I can have an instance of `MyDto` populate the first two properties based on convention, but I'm not sure how to tell Dapper to map all remaining columns into the dictionary.

```
connection.Query<MyDto>("Get_Something", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, param: parameters);
```

The stored procedure returns the following:

```
Id: INT
Code: VARCHAR(32)
Foo: VARCHAR(16)
Bar: DATETIME
```

Comment: Multimap with `splitOn: "Foo"` then map it yourself in the lambda? *EDIT* not trying to say you should have known this

Comment: @Charlieface: That's a big vague, even for me, and I'm experienced with Dapper in both it's dynamic and static modes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know, it was just a comment for someone with the time to write a full answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/correct-use-of-multimapping-in-dapper for further info

Comment: Ah, yes.  Multimapping.  Forgot about that.

Comment: The problem is that any solution is going to have to take into account both the static and dynamic aspects.  Id and string will probably have to be mapped manually, instead of relying on Dapper's reflection.

Comment: Is [your query of 10 months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839565/map-leftover-column-names-to-populate-a-dictionary-in-dapper-net) a duplicate?

Comment: @CaiusJard: Ah, I forgot that I asked this before. Maybe I should just bounty that and delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

Return your query as `dynamic` objects.

```
var query = connection.Query<dynamic>(
    "Get_Something", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, param: parameters);
```

Then, map your DTO's like this:

```
var results = new List<MyDto>();

foreach(item in query)
{
    var dictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(item).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
    var dto = new MyDto
    {
        Id = dictionary["Id"];
        Code = dictionary["Code"];
    }
    dictionary.Remove("Id");
    dictionary.Remove("Code");
    dto.AdditionalColumns = dictionary;
    results.Add(dto)
}
```

**Reference**
[RouteValueDictionary Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I wonder, would it make anything simpler to just leave the ID and Code in the dictionary and have the props of the class set/get them?